# Why is my mysql service won't start using xampp?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have tried to resolve, error on how to start mysql service on xampp.
I tried disabling the port on skype

What should I need to do to start MySQL using Xampp. Thanks in advance for the reply

Comment: Do you have apache2 service which is running ? I had that issue and solved it when i stopped apache2 service

Comment: Thanks for the comment. my apache2 service is currenly running in xampp control panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you have something running on `port 80`, like skype. You can either stop the service running on that port or open `httpd.conf` (in your XAMPP directory) and change the port to something else, change the following line

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

I chanced the port

from 80 to 8080 on httpd.conf

stopped the service and restart the xampp controller and restart apache and mysql service


mysql shows error  mysql shutdown unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was

```
To stop the  apache2 service in XAMPP control panel.
```

by carton